# Не работает auto-complete в VSCode при записи кода в {% %}

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

Auto-complete вообще не работает, когда я что-то пишу в HTML файле, то ни emmet, ни простое автодополнение не работает, меню не вылезает. Как исправить?

Кстати, я сносил VSCode, помогало до тех пор, пока я не начинаю использовать в коде `{% %}`.

Comment: Так вы используете не HTML, а EJS?

Comment: я не уверен что это EJS, я на flask. Я имел ввиду, что если я данную конструкцию записываю, то весь автокомлит слетает